# What to name functions that perform operations on strings that enter/exit db

Tags: naming-conventions

Need advice on what to name functions that do this

- Perform operations on strings before inserting into db to protect from MySQL injection
- Converts HTML special characters

Ex:

```
enter_db()
exit_db()
```

However, these function names sound kinda corny.  Any suggestions or advice on other names? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I decided to use PDO (prepared statements) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My database connection generally resides in a wrapper, so there's a bit of context for the functions:

```
//escapes data using standard methods - ie. mysql_real_escape_string()
$db->escapeData();
```

It sounds like you're making these functions external as part of a procedural library, and they do a little extra work on the string, so I'd probably go with something like:

```
sanitizeDbData();
```

I'm a PHP programmer, and PHP has a built in `htmlspecialchars()` function.  It's got a nice simplicity to it.  If you're not using PHP, I'd simply make `htmlSpecialChars()` the conversion function, or possibly `htmlEntities()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let call them 'encode' (make code) and decode (make it not a code).

Answer (score 0):

Here us what I would use:
Input_Validation_Function()

HTML_Char_converter()

I know those might not be the best names.  I hope it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to "scrub" a string for an problems before dumping it into your DB. You could think of this as a conversion function from one type of string to another type of string. You could then name your function RawStringToSafeString or SafeStr_from_RawStr or something similar. If you need functions in the other direction, then the naming is clear.

Converting html special characters would be similar: RawStringToConvertedString, etc. This reduces complexity because you only have to keep track of what type of string you're dealing with, not what conceptual actions have been performed on them.

This is a concept Joel talks about in one of his essays: http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: Thanks for the article, great insight!

Answer (score 0):

From a C# or .NET perspective (but also Java but using camel case) I would choose:

1. `Clean()` or `Sanitize()` is popular
2. `EncodeHtml()` `DecodeHtml()`